# Send a private message to an IRC bot

Tags: php, bots, irc

I have a php script to join a channel on this IRC server: irc.worldnet.net
Thanks to the server response I can say that I joined the channel successfully, and that the bot is in the users list. However, this command:

```
MSG bot_nickname hello my friend !
```

issues an 'msg: unknown command' response.
An when I send this line:

```
PRIVMSG bot_nickname : hello my friend !
```

There is no response from the bot (I don't have any error message anyway).
Is there something wrong with the commands I send ?

Here is the php code that I use:

```
<?php

$channel_sent = false;
$channel_joined = false;
$msg_sent = false;
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');

$config = array(
    'server' => 'irc.worldnet.net',
    'port' => 6667,
    'nick' => 'cesame'.rand(),
    'channel' => '#nc-irc-challs'
);

$server = array();
$server['SOCKET'] = @fsockopen($config['server'], $config['port'], $errno, $errstr, 2); 

if($server['SOCKET'])
{
    SendCommand("PASS NOPASS\n\r");
    SendCommand("NICK " . $config['nick'] . "\n\r"); 
    SendCommand("USER " . $config['nick'] . " USING PHP IRC\n\r");    
    SendCommand("JOIN " . $config['channel'] . "\n\r");

    while(!feof($server['SOCKET'])) {
            ReadServer();
            flush();
            sleep(1);
    }
}

function ReadServer(){
    global $server;
    global $config;
    global $channel_joined;
    global $channel_sent;
    global $msg_sent;
    $server['READ_BUFFER'] = fgets($server['SOCKET'], 1024);
    echo "[RECEIVE] ".$server['READ_BUFFER']."<br>\n\r";  

    if(substr($server['READ_BUFFER'], 0, 6) == "PING :") { 
        SendCommand("PONG :".substr($server['READ_BUFFER'], 6)."\n\r"); 
    }
    if(strpos($server['READ_BUFFER'], "#nc-irc-challs :End of /NAMES list")){
        $channel_joined = true;
    }
    if(trim($server['READ_BUFFER']) == "" && $channel_joined &&!$msg_sent) {
        SendCommand('PRIVMSG Daneel : .challenge_caesar start' . "\n\r");
        $msg_sent = true;
    }
}

function SendCommand ($cmd)
{
    global $server; //Extends our $server array to this function
    @fwrite($server['SOCKET'], $cmd, strlen($cmd)); //sends the command to the server
    echo "[SEND] $cmd <br>"; //displays it on the screen
} 

?>
```

---

So I followed you advices. This is the logs that I Get:

```
[RECEIVE] :cesame1582!~cesame158@Wnet-59540.41.55.213.rev.sfr.net JOIN :#nc-irc-challs 
[RECEIVE] :Vidar.IRC.Worldnet.Net 332 cesame1582 #nc-irc-challs :NewbieContest -- http://www.newbiecontest.org/ (channel officiel : #newbiecontest) -- Rappel : aucune Ã©preuve ne peut se rÃ©soudre en bruteforce. 
[RECEIVE] :Vidar.IRC.Worldnet.Net 333 cesame1582 #nc-irc-challs zours 1195848644 
[RECEIVE] :Vidar.IRC.Worldnet.Net 353 cesame1582 = #nc-irc-challs :cesame1582 \o_ @Eole +Daneel 
[RECEIVE] :Vidar.IRC.Worldnet.Net 366 cesame1582 #nc-irc-challs :End of /NAMES list. 
[SEND] PRIVMSG Daneel : .challenge_caesar start 
[RECEIVE] :Global!Services@Worldnet.Net NOTICE cesame1582 :[Logon News - Apr 07 2004] Use irc.worldnet.net to join our network, thanks | Dorenavant, utilisez irc.worldnet.net pour joindre notre reseau, merci. 
[RECEIVE] :Global!Services@Worldnet.Net NOTICE cesame1582 :[Logon News - Jan 07 2007] If you see a connection on port 23, 1080, 3128 or 8080 from 194.117.194.78 this is NOT an attack! It's our insecure proxy detector. 
[RECEIVE] :Global!Services@Worldnet.Net NOTICE cesame1582 :[Logon News - Feb 07 2007] Vous pouvez utiliser le port 7000 pour une connexion en SSL. You can use port 7000 with a secure SSL connection. 
[RECEIVE] :Global!Services@Worldnet.Net NOTICE cesame1582 :[Logon News - Oct 14 2009] Salons officiels du reseau Worldnet : #worldnet - #help pour de l'aide sur IRC et l'informatique en general. - ##opers pour les problemes réseau spécifiques à Worldnet. 
[RECEIVE] :Global!Services@Worldnet.Net NOTICE cesame1582 :[Random News - Apr 24 2004] Pour avoir de l'aide sur les commandes des services, visitez http://help.irc.worldnet.net 
[RECEIVE] :NickServ!Services@Worldnet.Net NOTICE cesame1582 :Your nick isn't registered. 
[RECEIVE] 
[RECEIVE] PING :Vidar.IRC.Worldnet.Net 
[SEND] PONG :Vidar.IRC.Worldnet.Net 
[RECEIVE] 
[RECEIVE] PING :Vidar.IRC.Worldnet.Net 
[SEND] PONG :Vidar.IRC.Worldnet.Net
```

Comment: What response are you expecting? I don't see anything here that would make your bot respond to that message.

Comment: this line:
SendCommand('PRIVMSG Daneel : .challenge_caesar start' . "\n\r");

I want to send to the bot "Daneel" ".challenge_caesar start" as a private message

Refer to the SendCommand function in the very bottom. thank you for your help :)

Comment: Okay, why would the server send you an empty string? It happens sometimes, but it doesn't mean the bot is idle. Instead, you should send the command as soon as you know the bot has joined the channel (at the end of the NAMES list).

Comment: I expect a random string as a response

Comment: `if(trim($server['READ_BUFFER']) == "" && $channel_joined &&!$msg_sent) {` Why would `$server['READ_BUFFER']` be empty?

Comment: Yes this is when I send the command right after the name list. I can see the bot on the list.

Comment: But `$server['READ_BUFFER']` will never be empty, so your if statement will fail every time.

Comment: the buffer is empty sometimes I can see in the logs that my message is sent. I get an error message if I use a wrong command instead of PRIVMSG

Comment: But you don't get the message on Daneel?

Comment: See the edit on my answer. That may be the cause as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IRC server generally does not send empty strings.

If you want a command to be issued once the BOT is in the channel, you should be sending it as soon as you know it's in the channel, which is at the end of the `/NAMES` list, or once you receive the `TOPIC`.

---

Also, the syntax for PRIVMSG is as follows:

```
PRIVMSG <NICKNAME> :<MESSAGE>
```

Without the space after the `:`. If the recieving end is set to respond to `.command` but gets  `.command`, that may be the problem.

Comment: Ok after suppressing the extra space character, I get the answer from the bot. Thanks a lot to all of you guys!