# IRC login with authentication send to NICKSERV if loggin try echo connected?

Tags: php, authentication, irc, fsockopen

Here is my code

```
<html>
<title></title>
<body>
    <form method="get" >
        Username: <input type="text" name="user"><br>
        Password: <input type="password" name="pwd"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <?php
//konfig
        $server = "XXXX";
        $port = "XXXX";
        $enable_password = true;
//error
        error_reporting(0);
        if (isset($_GET['user']) && isset($_GET['pwd'])) {
            $username = $_GET['user'];
            $password = $_GET['pwd'];
            if (($username !== "") && ($password !== "")) {
                set_time_limit(30);
                if (!($socket = fsockopen($server, $port, $errno, $errstr, 10))) {
                    echo "Cant Connect Server";
                    flush();
                } else {
                    if ($enable_password)
                        fputs($socket, "USER " . $username . "\n");
                    fputs($socket, "PASS " . $password . "\n");

                //get $line
                $line = @fgets($socket, 1024);
                if (strstr($line, "Authentication successful. You are now Login")) {
                    echo "Connected";
                } else {
                    echo "Not Connected";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
</body>
```

sock is installed in my PHP.
I try that and output is not connected while the username and password is true.
It required to identify username with password by sending /msg NICKSERV identify [passwd].
Any idea how to add that command to my script ? And hope result of output is correct while I input username and password..

Answer (score 0):

I found that topic:

[Send a private message to an IRC bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652500/send-a-private-message-to-an-irc-bot)

which has the following function:

```
function SendCommand ($cmd)
{
    global $server; //Extends our $server array to this function
    @fwrite($server['SOCKET'], $cmd, strlen($cmd)); //sends the command to the server
    echo "[SEND] $cmd <br>"; //displays it on the screen
}
```

so sending commands, as it is shown i.e.:

```
SendCommand("PONG :".substr($server['READ_BUFFER'], 6)."\n\r");
```

It seems you should follow schema like fwrite($socket, $cmd, strlen($cmd));